# C++ Operator overloading, my own string class

Tags: c++, string, c++11, operator-overloading

I'm trying to make my own string class in c++11 but I have some problems.
comparing my class to the std::string class, I can't figute out how to use the

std::string.at(int) = 'a'; method/overloading.

I've created the at(int) method in my own class:

```
int at(int index)
{
    if(index <0 || index > size-1) {throw std::out_of_range("Error, index out of range");}
    return data[index];
}
```

and it workd well if I only use:

```
MyString.at(2);
```

In the main file:

```
MyString = "Hello world!"; //Works fine!
MyString.at(2)='a'; //Gives, Error: expressino must be a modifiable Ivalue.
```

Any help with this would be great, Thanks!

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for the string class?

Comment: This is not the problem, but `index > size-1` can be written more idiomatically as `index >= size`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least one of your `at()` member functions needs to return a non-const reference to `char`. Like this:

```
char &at(std::size_t idx)
{
    return data[idx];
}
```

It would be beneficial to define a `const` version of the function too:

```
const char &at(std::size_t idx) const
{
    return data[idx];
}
```

Also note the use of `std::size_t` (which is an unsigned type guaranteed to be large enough to represent any size). This way you improve portability and you don't have to check for negative indices.

Comment: It might also be wise to have a const version.

Comment: Now I see the obvious problem! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @chris Fair enough. Do you mean that the member function itself should be `const` or the return value should be a reference-to-`const char`? (The former makes more sense, just checking.)

Comment: @H2CO3, Same as the subscripting operator overloads. Both combined.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning an integer and not a reference to the character, you probably want:

```
char& at(int index)
```

Of course, you need to return the correct character type, but in any case you need to return a reference in order for the caller to be able to assign to it.

Comment: Owooo.. how stupid I feel!
Thank you for your answer!